# Custom UIView not receiving touch events

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am building a custom slider to my application.

I found a library on Github as inspiration.

I have created the file: `NKSlider` as a subclass of `UIView` and implemented on it the `drawRect` as the library did and implemented the methods: `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesBegan:withEvent:`. But none of the touches events are being called.

this is how i add this custom view to my view controller:

```
NKHandler *nk = [[NKHandler alloc] init];
nk.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 36);
[self.view addSubview:nk];
[self.view addSubview:[[NKHandler alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 100)]];
```

and this are the classes. What am i doing wrong??

the `.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NKHandler : UIView

@end
```

and `.m`

```
#import "NKHandler.h"

static inline CGPoint CGPointTopCenter(CGRect rect) {
  CGPoint p; p.x = rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width / 2); p.y = rect.origin.y; return p;
}
static inline CGPoint CGPointBottomCenter(CGRect rect) {
  CGPoint p; p.x = rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width / 2); p.y = rect.origin.y + rect.size.height; return p;
}
static inline CGPoint CGPointLeftCenter(CGRect rect) {
  CGPoint p; p.x = rect.origin.x; p.y = rect.origin.y + (rect.size.height / 2); return p;
}
static inline CGPoint CGPointRightCenter(CGRect rect) {
  CGPoint p; p.x = rect.origin.x + rect.size.width; p.y = rect.origin.y + (rect.size.height / 2); return p;
}

@implementation NKHandler {
  int _selectedStep;
}

-(id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.clipsToBounds = NO;
    self.opaque = YES;

    _selectedStep = 5;   
  }
  return self;
}

-(void) setStep:(int) step {
  _selectedStep = step;
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {
  ... layout stuff ...
}
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  ... Boring drawing stuff ..
}

#pragma mark - Touch Handling

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
  [self setStep:(_selectedStep+1)%11];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

Comment: The designated initializer of `UIView` is `initWithFrame:` (and `initWithCoder` if you use Interface Builder), so when you call `[self.view addSubview:[[NKHandler alloc] initWithFrame:...`, your initialization code is never called.

Comment: in the code i posted i have 2 views added to my ``viewcontroller``, one is created with my custom ``init`` method, the other is created using ``initWithFrame:`` and in both of them the touches does`n work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nk.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the touches began to your custom class, then just calling super to pass them back up to your original view?

Comment: what original view? in my ViewController i add a subview, this subview is my custom view. There is no super of touches

Comment: Even so, you have a custom class (UIView) that is being added to your view as a subview. The touches are going to your subview and are not being handled. Handle touches there and just call super to pass them back up to your main view, not the subview.

Comment: aparently it was a bug, after clean an rebuild it was fixed, sorry about the late response

Answer (score 2):

If **userInteractionEnabled trick not works** maybe you should check the view's **parentview autosizing attributes**.

I changed it like this see below, because storyboard loaded it 'originally' in portrait mode, but I presented it in landscape, so the **parent's view height become 0 px**. And even dow the view itself kept its height the parents become 0 px so view did not get the event.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a super edge case, but I had this problem when accidentally had my custom view class descend from `UICollectionViewCell` in code, but in the XIB it the element used was `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this line cause trouble with UIView events:

```
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

This line can cause headaches after you've pushed and popped a view controller, using the pushViewController and popViewControllerAnimated methods. Once your contentView is displayed again, you may find event handling doesn't work.